# Submitting form by jquery using method=post

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

i want to submit a form by jquery. i write the query form as follow

```
$("#form").submit(function(event) {
    if(!$("#change").hasClass("has-error") && !$("#name1").hasClass("has-error") 
            && !$("#contact1").hasClass("has-error") && !$("#batch1").hasClass("has-error")){
            alert("submitting");
            event.preventDefault();
            var $form=$(this);
            name1=$("#name").val();
            contact1=$("#contact").val();
            email1=$("#email").val();
            city1=$form.find("input[name='city']").val();
            company1=$form.find("input[name='company']").val();
            url=$form.attr("action");
            var posting= $.post("some_link.php",{ name:name1,contact:contact1,email:email1,city:city1,company:company1});
            posting.done(function(data){
                alert("form submitted successfully");
                )
            })
            $("#reset").click();
            return false;

            }
    else return false;

});
```

but this is posting form by `GET` method not by `POST` method and also url form is redirected to other php page instead for remaining on this page.

here is how link look like 
`http://www.example.com/current_page.php?name=jhgjk&contact=lksjf&email=lkdj%40ldkjf.clj&city=&company=` but i want a normal post method as usually done by including `method="post"` in form

**EDIT** i got the mistake i was doing. i was missing a closing bracket for $.post and this was the reason the code was not working and i was banging my head.

Comment: Besides the fact that your code is full of mistakes. For example you use $-signs as variable names. But can you post your form?

Comment: Omg this hurts my head :(

Comment: @sanders $ sign in variable is perfectly acceptable in jQuery. and i cannot post the form by jquery. it is posted perfectly my standard html format by using action="something" and method="post"

Comment: @RichPeck you are not helping, are you?

Comment: Shouldn't the first argument to `$.post` be `url`, not `"some_link.php"`?

Comment: Did you check your javascript console for errors ? Put a break point in your javascript code, and check step by step if no error ever occurs in your callback.

Comment: @Barmar url is also "some_link.php" so it should doesn't matter at all. As it is also used in [jQuery api](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) page.

Comment: @LeGEC i manually debugged by using alert statement, but it was giving to alert in window. but when i commented `$.post` part, it was working and giving right alert statement in window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'd be much better using a technology called [$.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) :

```
$("#form").submit(function(e) {
    if(!$("#change").hasClass("has-error") && !$("#name1").hasClass("has-error") 
            && !$("#contact1").hasClass("has-error") && !$("#batch1").hasClass("has-error")){


            e.preventDefault();
            alert("submitting");

            $.ajax({ 
               url: 'some-link.php',
               type: 'POST',
               data: $(this).serialize(),
               success: function(data) {
                  alert('success!');
               },
               error: function(data) {
                  alert('error');
               }
            });


            }
    else return false;

});
```

Comment: yeah, i knew this method, this was my plan-B, but i really want to know why my code is not working

Comment: Okay, sorry. Personally, I like to stick to using as many pre-packaged functions as possible, as this removes the potential for bugs & errors. Ajax is one of those methods :)

Comment: still i don't know why my code is not working. I switched to plan-B and now its working :)

Comment: Isn't `$.post` even more "pre-packaged" than `$.ajax`?

Comment: Yep, but I like to use Ajax, so that's what I recommended :)

Comment: @Barmar Also, I was really recommended that the OP needed to clean up his code, to alleviate the potential for extensive bugs & errors. I'm no where near as experienced as yourself, so it would be cool if you let me know what you thought of my answer!

Comment: Your code is fine, it's just not clear why it fixes the OP's problem. There's no reason why `$.post` should send a `GET` request, and changing to `$.ajax` shouldn't change that.

Comment: Well to be honest, I looked at it & found there was stuff all over the place, so thought the best place to start would be to do some cleaning. That's where my suggestion came from, but will have to see if it fixed the problem!